# ElementaryOS Gala using more than 100% CPU constantly

Tags: xorg, drivers, elementary-os, ati, graphic-card

I am using ElementaryOS with the default Drivers and my Gala process is constantly using tons of CPU (sometimes more than 200%).

I have looked everywhere but couldnt find a solution. I tried to install the proprietary ATI drivers but then I can't login in the system (black screen).

My graphic card is an ATI Mobility Radeon 5730.

Here is the result of glxinfo command:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_texture, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_ARB_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_window_pos, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_NV_fog_distance, 
    GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_OES_read_format, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, 
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_ARB_robustness, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage
```

xorg.log file -> http://pastebin.com/acbCeMB5

Comment: Report to Elementary Os [bug tracker](https://launchpad.net/elementaryos)?

Comment: Already reported and no answer. Found some other users without similar issue but no conslusive solution.

Comment: That's an emulated graphics card - llvmpipe. You're not using your graphics card at all - it's all CPU. You've gotta figure out the ATI drivers. Phoronix.com is a pretty good place for info on Linux graphics. Here's more info on Gallium - http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html

Comment: thanks for the info.  i tried a couple of ati drivers from ati website before but all resulting in black screen after booting.

Comment: I added the link to my Xorg.log. @mikeserv I am searching for the Gallium thing. couldnt find a solution yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I finally fixed it!

I need to create a xorg.conf file and add set the correct driver to radeon; it was fbdev before.

```
Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                    # <str>
        #Option     "fbdev"                     # <str>
        #Option     "debug"                     # [<bool>]
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "radeon"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection
```

Now my glxinfo doesn't display libvmpipe anymore:

```
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD REDWOOD
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render,
```

Gala is using 0% CPU now.
@mikeserv, your comment pointed me into the right direction. I knew my X was being software rendered somehow, but didn't know exactly how. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you fixed it. I rarely hazard more than a comment on display driver questions - in a Unix environment the display driver is at the end of a chain of any number of other devices possibly/probably personally configured and so display problems tend to be very *personal* problems. Good work on sorting your issue.